# Explicit expression of a given power series

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Let us have a look to the power series of the form 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n+2}x^n},\ \ \ x\in\mathbb{R}$$
I want to find an explicit expression of this power series. I think one have to us the fact that one may change integration and summation in the area of convergence, but I don't see how to start. Can someone help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: Begin with $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n+1}$ and integrate.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n+2}x^n}=\frac{1}{x^2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n+2}x^{n+2}}$$

Now differentiate w.r.t. $x$ and obtain $f'(x)$ in explicit form. Then integrate the result.

Don't forget to check the convergence interval.

You will also need a particular value of the original series when integrating later. Use $f(0)=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: For $x=0$ one has to use the explicit expression and l'Hospital right?

Comment: @ErmelindaSalley, no, you won't be able to find the explicit expression without knowing some particular value of $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n+2}x^n$. To find $f(0)$ separate the first term (which is $\frac{1}{2}$ for any $x$, even $x=0$), then the rest will be $0$

Answer (score 1):

Another method $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n+1}=x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n=\frac{x}{1-x}\quad \textrm{for}\quad |x|< 1$$
Now, integrating term-wise we have $$\int\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n+1}\right)\text{d}x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int x^{n+1}\text{d}x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+2}}{n+2}=x^2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+2}x^n=\int \frac{x}{1-x}\text{d}x$$Hence $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+2}x^n=\frac{1}{x^2}\int\frac{x}{1-x}\text{d}x=-\frac{1}{x^2}\int\left(1+\frac{1}{x-1}\right)\text{d}x=-\frac{x+\ln|x-1|}{x^2}+C$$
Where $|x|\le 1\wedge x\ne 1$ (The series doesn't converge otherwise)(notice that we need to check $x=-1$ and by Leibniz it converges).

In order to find $C$ we need to find to which value the series converges. We have $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+2}x^n=\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+2}x^n\implies f(0)=\frac{1}{2}$$
On the other hand $$\lim_{x\to 0}-\frac{x+\ln(1-x)}{x^2}+C=\lim_{x\to 0}-\frac{x-x-\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^3)}{x^2}+C=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{2}+O(x)+C=\frac{1}{2}+C$$
Equating both expressions we get $C=0$, hence $$\boxed{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+2}x^n=-\frac{x+\ln(1-x)}{x^2}\quad\mathrm{for}\quad |x|\le 1,x\ne 1}$$

Comment: What about $x=0$?

Comment: And $x=1$, as you suggest the series converges for $|x| \leq 1$

Comment: @YuriyS, it should be $|x|\le 1\wedge x\ne 1$. Also, what about $x=0$? as I understand we should define to be $0.5$ and my solution doesn't reflect it.

Comment: @YuriyS, it was a typo. I will edit my  solution later.

Comment: @Yuriy S, using taylor it is easy to show that the limit is 0.5.

Comment: You are absolutely right